# vector iterator + offset out of range

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm new to using vectors and I'm pretty intermediate in knowing C++. I wanted to create a function that rotates an array a number of times and returns the array so I can have multiple arrays of the same vector but different rotations. I'm doing this so I can shift bits of an original array without changing the initial value of the array. Right now I'm really scratching my head. *The const 2d array is intentionally small as i know the size is irrelevant to my question.*

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const int myconsts[1][8] = { 
   { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
};
```

Here's my rotate function

```
int *RotateAndErase(int rotNum) {
  int Shifted[8];
  int vectAdd = 0;
  std::vector<int> Shift;
  Shift.resize(sizeof(myconsts[0]));

  do {
    // Adds the constants to each vector
    Shift.push_back(myconsts[0][vectAdd]);
    vectAdd++;
  } while (vectAdd < 8);
  // rotates desired direction(negative is right. positive is left)
  std::rotate(Shift.begin(), Shift.begin() + (rotNum), Shift.end());
  std::copy(Shift.begin(), Shift.end(), Shifted);
  return Shifted;
  Shift.erase(Shift.begin(), Shift.begin() + 8);
  delete Shifted;
}
```

How it's called in my class

```
class myclass {
 public:
  myclass() {
    int* Shift2 = RotateAndErase(2);
  }
}
```

How it's call in main

```
int main() {
    myclass();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not `const int myconsts[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};`? You are resizing by the number of bytes, not the number of elements in `myconsts[0]`

Comment: You've got some serious bugs in your code... the out of range is the least of your worries right now. For example, `return Shifted` returns a pointer to an local stack variable (bad) and then stops execution of the next 2 lines of code.

Comment: `delete Shifted;` makes no sense, since you didn't allocate `Shifted` with `new`.

Comment: Aside from your problem, some questions for you: First of all, why do you mix vectors and arrays? Only reason I'd see for that is to convert from one to the other, but other than that... Second, you might really want to read a tutorial. Why do you call erase? Can I assume that you have some experience in C and are not used to vector doing all the tedious stuff for you? Last thing, why do you use capitalized variable names? Quite unusual. I mean, of course one can use an unusual coding style, but I must say, I was confused at first, didn't thought of Shift as a variable at first glance.

Comment: @Aziuth I've never used vectors before. I come from a C and C# background I'm only just starting to use C++. I originally thought I only had to use vectors in order to rotate an array but I've found a much more simpler solution. I usually only capatilze variable names inside function

Comment: @RyanHaining The const 2d array is intentionally small as i know the size is irrelevant to my question. I put that there on purpose because I didn't want to put the full 2d array in the question. It was only to give you insight

Comment: @MarkLakata Don't worry I corrected those issues. I understand a how to use it a lot better

Comment: @Barmar I corrected those issues in a previous post where I edited the code. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Aziuth Another reason why I mixed vectors and array is because for whatever reason it wouldn't let me copy the same vector in multiple arrays and then rotate them. I was trying to do that so I didn't have to loop through an array each time I wanted to rotate an array. I wanted to future proof and have neater code for the future. Too bad I had no idea how to use vectors properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post made me feel very idiotic. The rest of my functions in my classes look nothing like this one. I figured out that I had to change the `Shift.resize()` to `Shift.reserve()`. I used `std::cout` to get the ***sizeof shift, int, and the size of my array*** then **added** them altogether and put them in `Shift.reserve()`. Also the rotation number **cannot** be higher than the number of elements in the vector after fiddling with the code it gave me the same error

Here's my refined code

```
std::vector<int> Rotate(int n, int arr[][8], int row) {
        int i = 0;
        std::vector<int> shift;
        //amount of bytes
        shift.reserve(sizeof(long) * 8);
        //amount of elements
        shift.resize(8);
        std::cout << "in: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            std::cout << arr[row][i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        do {
            shift[i] = arr[row][i];
            i++;
        } while (i < 8);
        std::rotate(shift.begin(), shift.begin() + (n % 8), shift.end());

        std::cout << "out: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            std::cout << shift[i] << " ";
        }
        return shift;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in this code. The one that causes the error is here:

```
std::vector<int> Shift;             # size is 0
Shift.resize(sizeof(myconsts[0]));  # size is 8*sizeof(int)

do {
Shift.push_back(myconsts[0][vectAdd]); # each push_back increases size by 1
vectAdd++;
} while (vectAdd < 8);
# size is now 8*sizeof(int) + 8
...
std::copy(Shift.begin(), Shift.end(), Shifted); # ouch! Shifted is int[8]
```

(You're also returning a pointer to a defunct local variable, but one thing at a time.)

**EDIT:** As Ryan Haining and Mark Lakata point out, I was mistaken about the size after `resize()`, it'll be 8*sizeof(int), not just 8.

Comment: `sizeof(myconsts[0])` probably returns 32, ie `8*sizeof(int)`

Comment: After the resize it'll be `8 * sizeof(int)`, not 8

Comment: @MarkLakata: You're right, my mistake. But the point still stands that it's >0.